# Button Center CSS

Tags: css, button, center

Usual CSS centering issue, just not working for me, the problem is that I don't know the finished width px

I have a div for the entire nav and then each button inside, they dont center anymore when there is more than one button. :(

```css
.nav {
  margin-top: 167px;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 34px;
}

.nav_button {
  height: 34px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav_button">
    <div class="b_left"></div>
    <div class="b_middle">Home</div>
    <div class="b_right"></div>

  </div>
  <div class="nav_button">
    <div class="b_left"></div>
    <div class="b_middle">Contact Us</div>
    <div class="b_right"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

---

**Result**

If the width is unknown, I did find a way a center the buttons, not entirely happy but doesnt matter, it works :D

The best way is to put it in a table

```
<table class="nav" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="nav_button">
            <div class="b_left"></div>
            <div class="b_middle">Home</div>
            <div class="b_right"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="nav_button">
            <div class="b_left"></div>
            <div class="b_middle">Contact Us</div>
            <div class="b_right"></div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 235, accepted):

I stumbled across this problem today and I got it to work with

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <button>button1</button>
    <button>button2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that a different element that has style of float right/left near this element may make this appear off-center.

Comment: I trust you're right, but is there a reason not to just do `<input class="btn btn-primary" style="text-align:center;display:block;" type="submit" value="{% trans 'ButtonPurpose' %}" />`

Answer (score 74):

Consider adding this to your CSS to resolve the problem:

```
button {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Best answer. No outside containers, (probably) no drawbacks.

Answer (score 25):

Another nice option is to use :

```
width: 40%;
margin-left: 30%;
margin-right: 30%
```

Comment: It works (and mekes sense) for Material UI, if the button is only one inside a `<Grid item>...</Grid>`

Comment: Oh nice idea :)

Answer (score 11):

The problem is with the following CSS line on `.nav_button`:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

That would only work if you had one button, that's why they're off-centered when there are more than one `nav_button` divs.

If you want all your buttons centered nest the `nav_buttons` in another div:

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="centerButtons">
        <div class="nav_button">
            <div class="b_left"></div>
            <div class="b_middle">Home</div>
            <div class="b_right"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav_button">
            <div class="b_left"></div>
            <div class="b_middle">Contact Us</div>
            <div class="b_right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And style it this way:

```
.nav{
    margin-top:167px;
    width:1024px;
    height:34px;
}

/* Centers the div that nests the nav_buttons */
.centerButtons {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
} 

.nav_button{
    height:34px;
    margin-right:10px;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your post, unfortunately doesnt work either, still all on the left.

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. It's because the .centerButtons is a block element and it takes up the whole space in .nav, rendering the margin properties useless. I tried to fix it by floating .centerButtons as well, but no luck.

Comment: yea i know its tricky one, annoys me coz i've done it before but cant remember how :).... any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Consider adding this to your CSS to resolve the problem:

```
.btn {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 40%;
  margin-right: 30%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you can write,

```
<div id="btn">
<button>Click</button>
</div>
```

if you work with JS instead of CSS, you can write this to move the button to center.

```
const bu = document.getElementById("btn");
bu.style.cursor="pointer";
bu.style.justifyContent="center";
bu.style.display="flex";
```

Answer (score -3):

when all else fails I just

```
<center> content </center>
```

I know its not "up to standards" any more, but if it works it works

Comment: This answer doesn't add anything to the other answers. `<center>` was deprecated in HTML4 and is not even supported in HTML5, which means it probably wont work if HTML5 is used.

Comment: I only use it if I can't get anything else to work. I have used it in pages where there is html5 but prefer not to. I have gone through and replaced what I could with `<div align="center">button</div>`

Comment: Deprecated tag, it's a bad practice to use it