# How to align two buttons

Tags: html, css

I have problem with align two buttons, I want to make something like this download button on this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYt2K.png .

I tried to add padding for left button and margin, but without success.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dvnd98x6/)

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> 

<div class="publish">
                        <button class="btplus"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button><button class="publishbt"> PUBLISH </br> NEWS </button>
                    </div>
```

css

```
.publish{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
display:inline-block;
margin-left:80px;
margin-top:12px;
}

    .publishbt{
    background-color:#FF6900;
    border:none;

    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    color:white;
        font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;

    font-weight:bold;
    padding:5px;

    }
    .btplus{
    background-color:#FF6900;
    border:none;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    color:white;
        font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    }
    .fa-plus-circle{
    margin-top:10px;
        }

    .buttonsearch{
    height:38px;
    width:100px;
    background-color: #36545f;
    border:none;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    }
    .fa-search{
    color:#dbe2e5;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Button Center CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622756/button-center-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a padding issue. You have unequal padding in your button elements. to make both of the buttons the same height, you need to make the padding same.

CSS:

```
.btplus{
   padding:15px 5px; /* no need for a bottom padding. if you want the bottom big, add corresponding padding to your text button too. */ 
vertical-align:top /* to align with the publish button, which has multiple lines*/  
} 
.fa-plus-circle{
margin:0px; /*no need for a margin. it pushes the circle down, but creates empty space. */
    }
.publishbt{
padding:6px 5px 7px; /*padding adjustment */
}
```

And you should take off the `<br/>` from inside the button too. it creates more empty space that is hard to match. If you want a big button, adjust padding to achieve it.

I updated the fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/Snowbell92/dvnd98x6/4/

Comment: check the new url. I missed adding font-awesome.

Comment: </br> tag is need, can you do with him. PUBLISH NEWS in two line

Comment: just increase the bottom padding by 1 px and you're good to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the `vertical-align` property on `btplus`. One possible solution is to set `vertical-align: middle` and increase the height of `publishbt` accordingly so that they align (`height: 43px`) worked well. You can explore further options of `vertical-align`.