# How do I center this button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a button that I am trying to center in the middle. If I specify the size it doesn't stay in the middle but shifts to the left.

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">

            <input class = "btn btn-block btn-primary col-md-2" type="submit" id="sumbit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
            </div>   

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Button Center CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3622756/button-center-css)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

it's center now if you don't want to change width.

```html
<center> <input class = "btn btn-block btn-primary col-md-2" type="submit" id="sumbit" name="submit" value="Login"/></center>
```

Comment: Please don't ever use the center tag, it is deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center. It's not even deprecated, it's obsolete.

Comment: This doesn't fix the incorrect code, just covers it up

Answer (score 4):

I see you are using Bootstrap classes so first off make sure you are including the Bootstrap css file in your head.

The problem is you have the 'btn-block' class on the btn which will make it take up the whole line and this will also stop the 'text-center' class from centering the button.

Just remove the `btn-block` class on the button so it only takes up the space needed for the buttons contents and allows it to be centred like an inline level element.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">

            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
            </div>   

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer here I think. As the OP is using bootstrap I think answers should include a way of achieving this using bootstrap instead of inline styles.

Answer (score -1):

You just add (style="text-align: center;) to div tag

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center" style="text-align: center;>

            <input class = "btn btn-block btn-primary col-md-2" type="submit" id="sumbit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
            </div>   

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding (style = "text-align: center";) solves the problem. Just make sure you add the second quotation mark after 'center'. I hope this helps

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center" style="text-align: center";>

            <input class = "btn btn-block btn-primary col-md-2" type="submit" id="sumbit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
            </div>   

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution will not work when Bootstrap is loaded as the btn-block class will make the button a block level element and therefore text-align: center will have no effect

Answer (score -2):

Try using the text-align: center CSS style element.

```html
<div style="text-align: center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col text-center">

            <input class = "btn btn-block btn-primary col-md-2" type="submit" id="sumbit" name="submit" value="Login"/>
            </div>   

    </div>
</div>
</div>
```